# Quartz long running job completes once and status returns to waiting but fails to reschedule

Tags: spring, quartz-scheduler

I've been having an issue with Quartz (version 1.6) failing to reschedule a long running job after the first completion. There are other jobs that reschedule fine but they do not usually run longer than the reiterate time. (I've been referring to the DB for job status) When the job starts it moves to state of BLOCKED, the prev_fire_time is set and the next_fire_time is set 1 minute in the future.

e.g next_fire_time = 9.50, prev_fire_time = 9.49

The job then doesn't finish until say 9.55. (Note: The job is responsible for batch updates on a backlog of transactions. Sometimes it takes 10 seconds sometimes it takes 10 minutes but the backlog can get large so we want to avoid setting the interval to 10 minutes.

When the job finishes the status is set back to WAITING but the next_fire_time remains in the past. Strangly i tried to setup a test in my local enviroment with a job that iterates every 10 seconds and sleeps for 1 minute and the scheduler seemed to handle it ok.

We use a custom Job Details Factory so I don't know if that could impact it.

I'm hoping for some suggestions on how to fix this. This is a legacy version of the product so upgrading libraries might be difficult if it requires large changes.

Details are:

```
<bean id="baseSchedulerFactory" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
    <property name="autoStartup" value="true"/>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="baseDataSource"/>
    <property name="waitForJobsToCompleteOnShutdown" value="true"/>
    <property name="overwriteExistingJobs" value="true"/>
    <property name="applicationContextSchedulerContextKey" value="applicationContext"/>
    <property name="triggers">
       <list>
            <ref bean="updateRecentlyModifedchedules" />
       </list>
   </property>
   <property name="quartzProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount">${org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount}</prop>
        </props>
   </property>
</bean>

<bean id="updateRecentlyModifedchedules" 
      class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SimpleTriggerBean" 
      depends-on="springApplicationContext">
   <property name="jobDetail" ref="updateRecentlyModifedchedulesJob" />
   <!-- delay for 280 seconds -->
   <property name="startDelay" value="280000" />
   <!-- repeat every 70 seconds -->
   <property name="repeatInterval" value="70000" />
</bean>

<bean id="updateRecentlyModifedchedulesJob" class="com.app.application.backoffice.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetal">
   <property name="targetBeanName" value="scheduleChangeManager" />
   <property name="targetMethod" value="assetSchedules" />
   <property name="concurrent" value="false" />
</bean>
```

And the custom job factory:

```
public class MethodInvokingJobDetal implements FactoryBean, BeanNameAware, BeanClassLoaderAware, 
BeanFactoryAware, InitializingBean 
{
private String name;
private String group = Scheduler.DEFAULT_GROUP;
private boolean concurrent = true;
private String targetBeanName;
private String[] jobListenerNames;
private String beanName;
private ClassLoader beanClassLoader = ClassUtils.getDefaultClassLoader();
private BeanFactory beanFactory;
private JobDetail jobDetail;
private String targetMethod;

public void setTargetMethod(String targetMethod)
{
    this.targetMethod = targetMethod;
}

public void setName(String name) 
{
    this.name = name;
}

public void setGroup(String group)
{
    this.group = group;
}

public void setConcurrent(boolean concurrent) 
{
    this.concurrent = concurrent;
}

public void setTargetBeanName(String targetBeanName) 
{
    this.targetBeanName = targetBeanName;
}

public void setJobListenerNames(String[] names) 
{
    this.jobListenerNames = names;
}

public void setBeanName(String beanName) 
{
    this.beanName = beanName;
}

public void setBeanClassLoader(ClassLoader classLoader) 
{
    this.beanClassLoader = classLoader;
}

public void setBeanFactory(BeanFactory beanFactory) 
{
    this.beanFactory = beanFactory;
}

protected Class<?> resolveClassName(String className) throws ClassNotFoundException 
{
    return ClassUtils.forName(className, this.beanClassLoader);
}


protected void prepare() 
{
}

public void afterPropertiesSet() throws ClassNotFoundException, NoSuchMethodException 
{
    prepare();

    // Use specific name if given, else fall back to bean name.
    String name = (this.name != null ? this.name : this.beanName);

    // Consider the concurrent flag to choose between stateful and stateless job.
    Class<?> jobClass = (this.concurrent ? (Class<?>) MyMethodInvokingJob.class 
            : StatefulMyMethodInvokingJob.class);

    // Build JobDetail instance.
    this.jobDetail = new JobDetail(name, this.group, jobClass);
    this.jobDetail.getJobDataMap().put("targetBeanName", targetBeanName);
    this.jobDetail.getJobDataMap().put("targetMethod", targetMethod);
    this.jobDetail.setVolatility(false);
    this.jobDetail.setDurability(true);

    // Register job listener names.
    if (this.jobListenerNames != null) 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < this.jobListenerNames.length; i++) 
        {
            this.jobDetail.addJobListener(this.jobListenerNames[i]);
        }
    }

    postProcessJobDetail(this.jobDetail);
}

/**
 * Callback for post-processing the JobDetail to be exposed by this FactoryBean.
 * <p>The default implementation is empty. Can be overridden in subclasses.
 * @param jobDetail the JobDetail prepared by this FactoryBean
 */
protected void postProcessJobDetail(JobDetail jobDetail) 
{
}


/**
 * Overridden to support the {@link #setTargetBeanName "targetBeanName"} feature.
 */
public Class<?> getTargetClass() 
{
    Class<?> targetClass = null; //super.getTargetClass();

    if (targetClass == null && this.targetBeanName != null) 
    {
        Assert.state(this.beanFactory != null, "BeanFactory must be set when using 'targetBeanName'");
        targetClass = this.beanFactory.getType(this.targetBeanName);
    }

    return targetClass;
}

/**
 * Overridden to support the {@link #setTargetBeanName "targetBeanName"} feature.
 */
public Object getTargetObject() 
{
    Object targetObject = null; // super.getTargetObject();

    if (targetObject == null && this.targetBeanName != null) 
    {
        Assert.state(this.beanFactory != null, "BeanFactory must be set when using 'targetBeanName'");
        targetObject = this.beanFactory.getBean(this.targetBeanName);
    }

    return targetObject;
}


public Object getObject() 
{
    return this.jobDetail;
}

public Class<?> getObjectType() 
{
    return JobDetail.class;
}

public boolean isSingleton() 
{
    return true;
}

public static class StatefulMyMethodInvokingJob extends MyMethodInvokingJob 
implements StatefulJob 
{

    // No implementation, just an addition of the tag interface StatefulJob
    // in order to allow stateful method invoking jobs.
}

private static class MyMethodInvokingJob extends QuartzJobBean
{
    private String targetBeanName;
    private String targetMethod;

    public void setTargetBeanName(String targetBeanName)
    {
        this.targetBeanName = targetBeanName;
    }

    public void setTargetMethod(String targetMethod)
    {
        this.targetMethod = targetMethod;
    }

    @Override
    protected void executeInternal(JobExecutionContext context)
            throws JobExecutionException
    {
        Object targetObject = SpringApplicationContext.getBean(targetBeanName);

        try
        {
            Method method = targetObject.getClass().getMethod(targetMethod);
            method.invoke(targetObject);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, issue solved. Time on the DB Server and time on the App server were out.